# How can I split a pandas dataframe, where the timestep between data is greater than 1 second?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data which is recorded from a system and I want to split it whenever it is turned on and off. The system records consistantly at a 1s period, so I can just split the data whenever there is a gap greater than 1 second to find when the system was on/off

The dataframe is indexed as a timeseries, and so far I am using:

```
idx = df.index.to_series().diff().dt.seconds > 1
```

To find where to split the data. However I cant work out how to then split the main df into smaller chunks, at these locations.  How can I split a dataframe at the locations marked as "True" in idx?

Here is some sample data:

```
dataloggertime                      speedoverground
2021-02-01 12:38:21.331000+00:00    0.011887
2021-02-01 12:38:22.331000+00:00    0.011887
2021-02-01 12:38:23.331000+00:00    0.015545
2021-02-01 12:38:24.331000+00:00    0.015545
2021-02-01 12:38:25.331000+00:00    0.002438
2021-02-01 12:38:26.331000+00:00    0.010668
2021-02-01 12:38:27.332000+00:00    0.020117
2021-02-01 12:38:28.331000+00:00    0.016764
2021-02-01 12:38:29.331000+00:00    0.038710
2021-02-01 13:55:19.332000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:20.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:21.334000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:22.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:23.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:24.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:25.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:26.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:27.332000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:28.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:29.332000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:30.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:31.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:32.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:33.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:34.331000+00:00         NaN
2021-02-01 13:55:35.331000+00:00    0.021031
2021-02-01 13:55:36.333000+00:00    0.019507
2021-02-01 13:55:37.331000+00:00    0.012192
2021-02-01 13:55:38.332000+00:00    0.008839
2021-02-01 13:55:39.331000+00:00    0.008839
2021-02-01 13:55:40.332000+00:00    0.010363
2021-02-01 13:55:41.331000+00:00    0.010363
2021-02-01 13:55:42.340000+00:00    0.010363
2021-02-01 13:55:43.330000+00:00    0.011887
2021-02-01 13:55:44.331000+00:00    0.007010
2021-02-01 13:55:45.330000+00:00    0.008230
2021-02-01 13:55:46.331000+00:00    0.005486
2021-02-01 13:55:47.331000+00:00    0.018898
2021-02-01 13:55:48.332000+00:00    0.024384
2021-02-01 13:55:49.331000+00:00    0.008230
```

And the expected result:

DF1:

```
dataloggertime                      speedoverground
2021-02-01 12:38:21.331000+00:00    0.011887
2021-02-01 12:38:22.331000+00:00    0.011887
2021-02-01 12:38:23.331000+00:00    0.015545
2021-02-01 12:38:24.331000+00:00    0.015545
2021-02-01 12:38:25.331000+00:00    0.002438
2021-02-01 12:38:26.331000+00:00    0.010668
2021-02-01 12:38:27.332000+00:00    0.020117
2021-02-01 12:38:28.331000+00:00    0.016764
2021-02-01 12:38:29.331000+00:00    0.038710
```

DF2:

```
dataloggertime                      speedoverground
2021-02-01 13:55:35.331000+00:00    0.021031
2021-02-01 13:55:36.333000+00:00    0.019507
2021-02-01 13:55:37.331000+00:00    0.012192
2021-02-01 13:55:38.332000+00:00    0.008839
2021-02-01 13:55:39.331000+00:00    0.008839
2021-02-01 13:55:40.332000+00:00    0.010363
2021-02-01 13:55:41.331000+00:00    0.010363
2021-02-01 13:55:42.340000+00:00    0.010363
2021-02-01 13:55:43.330000+00:00    0.011887
2021-02-01 13:55:44.331000+00:00    0.007010
2021-02-01 13:55:45.330000+00:00    0.008230
2021-02-01 13:55:46.331000+00:00    0.005486
2021-02-01 13:55:47.331000+00:00    0.018898
2021-02-01 13:55:48.332000+00:00    0.024384
2021-02-01 13:55:49.331000+00:00    0.008230
```

Comment: Simply `df[idx]` and `df[~idx]` ?

Comment: @forgetso I am looking to split each time the system is turned on and off into a separate dataframe, rather than just slicing the main dataframe where the system is on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
g = (df.index.to_series().diff().dt.seconds > 1).cumsum()
print (g.head(15))
dataloggertime
2021-02-01 12:38:21.331000+00:00    0
2021-02-01 12:38:22.331000+00:00    0
2021-02-01 12:38:23.331000+00:00    0
2021-02-01 12:38:24.331000+00:00    0
2021-02-01 12:38:25.331000+00:00    0
2021-02-01 12:38:26.331000+00:00    0
2021-02-01 12:38:27.332000+00:00    0
2021-02-01 12:38:28.331000+00:00    0
2021-02-01 12:38:29.331000+00:00    0
2021-02-01 13:55:19.332000+00:00    1
2021-02-01 13:55:20.331000+00:00    1
2021-02-01 13:55:21.334000+00:00    1
2021-02-01 13:55:22.331000+00:00    1
2021-02-01 13:55:23.331000+00:00    1
2021-02-01 13:55:24.331000+00:00    1
Name: dataloggertime, dtype: int32
```

If need groups:

```
for i, gr in df.groupby(g):
    print (gr.dropna())
```

Comment: I am looking to split each time the system is turned on and off into a separate dataframe, rather than just slicing the main dataframe where the system is on

Comment: @TomMcLean - Can you add some small data sample (5-10 rows\) to your question with expected ouput? Hard test solution without data

Comment: @jazrael Sure, I have added some data. There will be more than one section where there will be a break in the data, so it will need to split into 2, 3, 4, or more dataframes depending on how many gaps there are. Thanks!

Comment: @TomMcLean - Is possible add expected ouput after break from sample data? there should be 2 DataFrames? Or more? It seems you forget add it to question.

Comment: @TomMcLean - Added soemthing to answer, but not sure if understand.

Comment: Thanks, thats pretty much what I wanted to do! Sorry, I'm kind of new to stack overflow so still learning on how to post a properly formatted question to make it easier to answer. Thanks for that!

Comment: @TomMcLean - No problem, if you are new, maybe help in future this - [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)